# Is there a max length to java_opts arguments on a tomcat process

Tags: redhat, tomcat, rhel5

We have a tomcat startup script with a java_opts that contains a fairly lengthy (around 14 hosts) entry for -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts, I've noticed that although tomcat appears to start properly, entries at the end will still proxy. When moving the entries to the start of the list, they bypass the proxy settings as you would expect. Is there a limit on either the overall JAVA_OPTS or specifically on the -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts directive that would not cause a startup error? This is on RHEL 5.10 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a single -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts with many hosts or many such options for each host?

Comment: single entry - the nonProxyHosts segment is about 350 chars, while JAVA_OPTS altogether is about 860 chars

Comment: Can you show your syntax?